# Power changes as factor labels change?

Tags: r, regression, interaction, statistical-power

Assume we have a simple linear regression of the form `Val ~ Group*Sex`, with both `Group` and `Sex` being factors with two values. For simulation purposes I'm interested in the power of the `Group` effect, i.e. how often $Pr(>|t_{Group}|) < 0.05$

It stands to reason that labels for the factors are arbitrary, and hence exchanging labels may change the sign of some coefficient, but surely they should not change the power of an effect. Right?

Well, the power changes:

```
sim = function(label1='F', label2='M', n=40, mu=0.6343) {
  a  = rnorm(n,   0.0, 1)
  b1 = rnorm(n/2, mu - mu/4, 1)
  b2 = rnorm(n/2, mu + mu/4, 1) # interaction is mu/2
  dat = data.frame(Group = as.factor(c(rep("C", n), rep("T", n))),
                   Sex   = as.factor(rep(c(rep(label1, n/2), rep(label2, n/2)), 2)),
                   Val   = c(a, b1, b2))
  fit   = lm(Val ~ Group*Sex, dat)
  return(summary(fit)$coefficients)
}

# results in ~0.32 power
res1=sapply(1:1000, function(x) sim('F', 'M'))
mean(res1[14,]<0.05) # power Treatment effect

# results in ~0.7 power
res2=sapply(1:1000, function(x) sim('M', 'F'))
mean(res2[14,]<0.05) # power Treatment effect
```

What is the error in my reasoning? (hopefully no error in code)
Why does the power change when all I do is exchange some labels?

Comment: Why don't you compute power in the usual way, by taking repeated samples with replacement from your target population (presuming your population is not finite) and computing the value of the test statistic of interest for each such sample? It's also not clear to me what you are trying to power your test for? Detecting the main effect of Group? (This effect may or not be interpretable given the presence of the interaction between Group and Sex in your model.)

Comment: @IsabellaGhement: Thank you for responding. I'm taking repeated samples from the target population (=normal distribution) with `mu=0` for the control (`a`), `mu=30` for half of treatment (`b1`), and `mu=50` for other half of treatment (`b2`). I'm running 1000 "studies" and look at how many coefficients for the treatment (`b1+b2`) are significant (`<0.05`). For sake of brevity I don't care about the coefficients themselves nor about the significance of other coefficients. The result of this simulation: the power of the treatment effect changes substantially. The question is why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]It looks like you are simulating from the following model:

Val = beta0 + beta1*GroupT + beta2*SexM + beta3*GroupT*SexM + error

I modified your function to enable me to see what values of beta0, beta1, beta2 and beta3 you used for (1) label1='F', label2='M' and (2) label1='M', label2='F'.  The modified function is here:

```
sim <- function(label1='F', label2='M', n=40, mu=0.6343) {

    a  <- rnorm(n,   0.0, 1)
    b1 <- rnorm(n/2, mu - mu/4, 1)
    b2 <- rnorm(n/2, mu + mu/4, 1) # interaction is mu/2
    dat <- data.frame(Group = as.factor(c(rep("C", n), rep("T", n))),
                 Sex   = as.factor(rep(c(rep(label1, n/2), 
                                 rep(label2, n/2)), 2)),
                 Val   = c(a, b1, b2))

    fit <- lm(Val ~ Group*Sex, dat)

    b0 <- summary(fit)$coefficients[1]
    b1 <- summary(fit)$coefficients[2]
    b2 <- summary(fit)$coefficients[3]
    b3 <- summary(fit)$coefficients[4]

    # pvalue for testing Ho: beta1 = 0 vs Ha: beta1 != 0
    pval  <-  summary(fit)$coefficients["GroupT","Pr(>|t|)"]

    # return(summary(fit)$coefficients)

    return(list(b0=b0, b1=b1, b2=b2, b3=b3, pval=pval))

}
```

I then called the modified function separately for each of your two scenarios and plotted the simulation distributions of the estimated values of beta0, beta1, beta2 and beta3 via histograms.  For each histogram, I plotted the mean of the estimated values of the corresponding parameter using a dotted, vertical red line and interpreted that as the "truth".

**Scenario 1: label1='F', label2='M'**

```
set.seed(17)   

b0 <- NULL 
b1 <- NULL 
b2 <- NULL 
b3 <- NULL 
pval <- NULL 
for (i in 1:1000) { 
     simres <- sim('F', 'M')
     b0 <- c(b0, simres$b0) 
     b1 <- c(b1, simres$b1)
     b2 <- c(b2, simres$b2) 
     b3 <- c(b3, simres$b3) 
     pval <- c(pval, simres$pval)

}

power <- sum(ifelse(pval < 0.05, 1, 0))/length(pval)*100
power

par(mfrow=c(2,4))
hist(b0, col="lightblue")
abline(v=mean(b0), col="red", lty=2, lwd=2)
hist(b1, col="lightblue")
abline(v=mean(b1), col="red", lty=2, lwd=2)
hist(b2, col="lightblue")
abline(v=mean(b2), col="red", lty=2,lwd=2)
hist(b3, col="lightblue")
abline(v=mean(b3), col="red", lty=2, lwd=2)
```

**Scenario 2: label1='M', label2='F'**

```
set.seed(17)   

b0 <- NULL 
b1 <- NULL 
b2 <- NULL 
b3 <- NULL 
pval <- NULL 
for (i in 1:1000) {
     simres <- sim('M', 'F')
     b0 <- c(b0, simres$b0) 
     b1 <- c(b1, simres$b1)
     b2 <- c(b2, simres$b2) 
     b3 <- c(b3, simres$b3) 
     pval <- c(pval, simres$pval)

}


power <- sum(ifelse(pval < 0.05, 1, 0))/length(pval)*100
power


hist(b0, col="lightgreen")
abline(v=mean(b0), col="blue", lty=2, lwd=2)
hist(b1, col="lightgreen")
abline(v=mean(b1), col="blue", lty=2, lwd=2)
hist(b2, col="lightgreen")
abline(v=mean(b2), col="blue", lty=2,lwd=2)
hist(b3, col="lightgreen")[![enter image description here][1]][1]
abline(v=mean(b3), col="blue", lty=2, lwd=2)
```

For both scenarios, it looks like you are simulating based on beta0 = 0 and beta2 = 0.  However, the values of beta1 and beta3 are different across the two scenarios.  Indeed, beta1 is approximately 0.5 for Scenario 1 and 0.8 for Scenario 2. On the other hand, beta3 is approximately 0.3 for Scenario 1 and -0.3 for Scenario 2 (note the change of sign).  See the attached figure for an illustration of this - the top row of the figure presents results from Scenario 1 while the bottom row presents results from Scenario 2.  (In the above code, b0, b1, b2 and b3 represent the estimated values of beta0, beta1, beta2 and beta3, respectively.)

Given this discrepancy in the values of beta1 and beta3 across your two simulation scenarios, it is not surprising that you are seeing different values for your (estimated) power.

In my view, it is cleaner to simulate your data directly from the model, so that you really understand what is going on and how one simulation scenario differs from another:

Val = beta0 + beta1*GroupT + beta2*SexM + beta3*GroupT*SexM + error

For example, just set beta0 = 0, beta1 = 0.5, beta2=0 and beta3=0.3 in the above to recover your Scenario 1:

```
beta0 <- 0

beta1 <- 0.5 

beta2 <- 0

beta3 <- 0.3

Group <- as.factor(c(rep("C", n), rep("T", n)))

Sex   <- as.factor(rep(c(rep(label1, n/2), rep(label2, n/2)), 2))

GroupT <- ifelse(Group=="T",1,0)

SexM <- ifelse(Sex=="M",1,0)

Val <- beta0 + beta1*GroupT + beta2*SexM + beta3*GroupT*SexM + 
       rnorm(n=80, mean=0, sd=1)

dat <- data.frame(Group=Group, Sex=Sex, Val=Val)
```

Now you can fit the model to the generated data as a check and plot the interaction between Group and Sex:

```
fit <- lm(Val ~ Group*Sex, dat)

summary(fit)

interaction.plot(dat$Group, dat$Sex, dat$Val)
```

The simulation function for this more direct way of generating data would look something like this:

```
sim <- function(beta0=0, beta1=0.5, beta2=0, beta3=0.3, n=80) {

   Group <- as.factor(c(rep("C", n), rep("T", n)))

   Sex <- as.factor(rep(c(rep(label1, n/2), rep(label2, n/2)), 2))

   GroupT <- ifelse(Group=="T",1,0)

   SexM <- ifelse(Sex=="M",1,0)

   Val <- beta0 + beta1*GroupT + beta2*SexM + beta3*GroupT*SexM + 
          rnorm(n=80, mean=0, sd=1)

   dat <- data.frame(Group=Group, Sex=Sex, Val=Val)  

   fit <- lm(Val ~ Group*Sex, dat)

   b0 <- summary(fit)$coefficients[1]
   b1 <- summary(fit)$coefficients[2]
   b2 <- summary(fit)$coefficients[3]
   b3 <- summary(fit)$coefficients[4]

   # pvalue for testing Ho: beta1 = 0 vs Ha: beta1 != 0
   pval  <-  summary(fit)$coefficients["GroupT","Pr(>|t|)"]

   # return(summary(fit)$coefficients)

   return(list(b0=b0, b1=b1, b2=b2, b3=b3, pval=pval))

}
```

Comment: Looking at the model as you presented it it is clear now how statistical power changes. I'm still feeling a bit uneasy that I potentially can p-hack effects to significance by changing group labels... Thanks for your thorough answer.